# Fluent apply RuleFor only if value is not null

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

Following on from my previous question, I have a `nullable` `char` named `source` in my `Transaction` class.

```
    //source isnt required but when present must be 1 character 'I' or 'M'            
    RuleFor(transaction => transaction.source.ToString())
        .Matches("^[IM]?$")                
        .When(t => t.source.Value != null);
```

As `Matches` and `When` are not available for a `char`, I am using the `.ToString()` method however, if when a new `Transaction` object is generated, the source property is `null`, the application fails due to being unable to convert a `null` source to a `string`.

Can anyone suggest a way of running the validation for source **ONLY** if source is not `null`? I assumed that the When expression that I have written would do this, and this part of the validation process would be skipped if source was `null` however it tries to process the `ToString()` part of the validation regardless and thus causes an error.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Matches` and `When` are available for the `char` datatype.

I would suggest something like this...

```
public class Transaction
{
    public char? source { get; set; }
}


public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Transaction>
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(t => t.source)
            .Must(IsValidSource);
    }


    private bool IsValidSource(char? source)
    {
        if (source == 'I' || source == 'M' || source == null)
            return true;
        return false;                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not know whole context but I see one most obvious solution here:

```
RuleFor(transaction => transaction.source != null ? transaction.source.ToString() : string.Empty)
    .Matches("^[IM]?$")
```